# Can I create the controller in unity as well?

Tags: airconsole

I would like to make the controller just like I make the game. Using Unity and exporting to webgl.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The AirConsole Unity plugin is not implemented in a way to act as an AirConsole controller. Also it you probably would run into performance and WebGl-support issues for especially older devices.